# Proxy Contracts Initializing problems

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts

Good afternoon. I’ll be brief - there is a Module in my ecosystem, the module is initialized by the proxy factory DeployProxy.sol and then the proxy contract address is entered into the Core contract and managed from there.

Problem: I can’t initialize the proxy contract through the script.

DeployProxy.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/ProxyAdmin.sol";

contract DeployProxy is Ownable {
    ProxyAdmin private proxyAdmin;

    event ProxyCreated(address proxy);

    constructor() {
        proxyAdmin = new ProxyAdmin();
    }

    function deployNewModule(address _logic, bytes memory _data) public onlyOwner returns (address) {
        TransparentUpgradeableProxy proxy = new TransparentUpgradeableProxy(_logic, address(proxyAdmin), _data);
        emit ProxyCreated(address(proxy));
        return address(proxy);
    }


    // Функция для обновления существующего прокси-контракта
    function upgradeModule(address _proxy, address _newLogic) public onlyOwner {
        // Приведение адреса прокси к интерфейсу ITransparentUpgradeableProxy
        ITransparentUpgradeableProxy proxy = ITransparentUpgradeableProxy(_proxy);
        proxyAdmin.upgrade(proxy, _newLogic);
    }

    // Другие функции...
}
```

initTransfer.js

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const coreAddress = "0x6e349b1594346d30Fe9F7cEd65f660573c611062"; // Адрес контракта BulkifyCore
    const DeployProxy = await ethers.getContractFactory("DeployProxy");
    const deployProxy = await DeployProxy.attach("0x923A0a666130D3525F653fb1C026D925416a005D"); // Адрес контракта DeployProxy

    const TransferModule = await ethers.getContractFactory("TransferModule");
    const transferModuleLogicAddress = "0xA23b7E2cfaee4A854A9F1A5968eDe39769b2cB6c"; // Замените на актуальный адрес логики TransferModule

    // Получаем интерфейс ABI контракта
    const initData = TransferModule.interface.encodeFunctionData("initialize", [coreAddress]);

    // Вызываем функцию deployNewModule для развертывания нового модуля через прокси
    deployTx = await deployProxy.deployNewModule(transferModuleLogicAddress, initData, {
        gasLimit: 1000000
    });
    deployReceipt = await deployTx.wait();

    console.log("TransferModule deployed at:", deployReceipt.events[0].args.proxy);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Error

```
Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0xbd4fa71beb020a63b4ab335ea9f922a5861f59e10322ed51677b16d64dd9dd70", transaction={"hash":"0xbd4fa71beb020a63b4ab335ea9f922a5861f59e10322ed51677b16d64dd9dd70","type":2,"accessList":[],"blockHash":null,"blockNumber":null,"transactionIndex":null,"confirmations":0,"from":"0x4e29E00Ce9a65454Ce5B92DA1176871d321c1837","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0e9a6ec594"},"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x3b9aca00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0e9a6ec594"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0f4240"},"to":"0x923A0a666130D3525F653fb1C026D925416a005D","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"nonce":13,"data":"0x7645f72e000000000000000000000000a23b7e2cfaee4a854a9f1a5968ede39769b2cb6c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024c4d66de80000000000000000000000006e349b1594346d30fe9f7ced65f660573c61106200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","r":"0xa335e5d33694990457dd13e0915902d482721654a2c9db09b8b97214578cfe7c","s":"0x025815f7efb992c2546220d3cb1853546ec0c358ae888467e9c76516448657c5","v":0,"creates":null,"chainId":11155111}, receipt={"to":"0x923A0a666130D3525F653fb1C026D925416a005D","from":"0x4e29E00Ce9a65454Ce5B92DA1176871d321c1837","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":43,"gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x020c71"},"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","blockHash":"0x7fe4380b30e88d79bbd38396368149e6b6e3142886cd4eb7bd0d5ced51a4a664","transactionHash":"0xbd4fa71beb020a63b4ab335ea9f922a5861f59e10322ed51677b16d64dd9dd70","logs":[],"blockNumber":5133791,"confirmations":1,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x57f597"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0bc56d925c"},"status":0,"type":2,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/zoho/Desktop/BulkifyProtocol/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/zoho/Desktop/BulkifyProtocol/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.<anonymous> (/Users/zoho/Desktop/BulkifyProtocol/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/base-provider.ts:1549:24)
    at step (/Users/zoho/Desktop/BulkifyProtocol/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/zoho/Desktop/BulkifyProtocol/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/zoho/Desktop/BulkifyProtocol/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:20:58) {
  reason: 'transaction failed',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  transactionHash: '0xbd4fa71beb020a63b4ab335ea9f922a5861f59e10322ed51677b16d64dd9dd70',
  transaction: {
    hash: '0xbd4fa71beb020a63b4ab335ea9f922a5861f59e10322ed51677b16d64dd9dd70',
    type: 2,
    accessList: [],
    blockHash: null,
    blockNumber: null,
    transactionIndex: null,
    confirmations: 0,
    from: '0x4e29E00Ce9a65454Ce5B92DA1176871d321c1837',
    gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "62720492948" },
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1000000000" },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "62720492948" },
    gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "1000000" },
    to: '0x923A0a666130D3525F653fb1C026D925416a005D',
    value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
    nonce: 13,
    data: '0x7645f72e000000000000000000000000a23b7e2cfaee4a854a9f1a5968ede39769b2cb6c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024c4d66de80000000000000000000000006e349b1594346d30fe9f7ced65f660573c61106200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    r: '0xa335e5d33694990457dd13e0915902d482721654a2c9db09b8b97214578cfe7c',
    s: '0x025815f7efb992c2546220d3cb1853546ec0c358ae888467e9c76516448657c5',
    v: 0,
    creates: null,
    chainId: 11155111,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  receipt: {
    to: '0x923A0a666130D3525F653fb1C026D925416a005D',
    from: '0x4e29E00Ce9a65454Ce5B92DA1176871d321c1837',
    contractAddress: null,
    transactionIndex: 43,
    gasUsed: BigNumber { value: "134257" },
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockHash: '0x7fe4380b30e88d79bbd38396368149e6b6e3142886cd4eb7bd0d5ced51a4a664',
    transactionHash: '0xbd4fa71beb020a63b4ab335ea9f922a5861f59e10322ed51677b16d64dd9dd70',
    logs: [],
    blockNumber: 5133791,
    confirmations: 1,
    cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { value: "5764503" },
    effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { value: "50556932700" },
    status: 0,
    type: 2,
    byzantium: true
  }
}
```

Comment: When I put it into tenderly.co I get `invalid opcode: BLOBBASEFEE`.  Not sure if this helps you but, if not, I'm sure you can find your answer using tenderly.co FWIW.

Comment: @ruby_newbie i don’t know why you type this because it's not helped to me. I need to know, why if I'm owner of all contracts I can't call function and have error “You are not the owner”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also find answer.

Core contract interact with DeployProxy contract. That’s true. Then DeployProxy contract have internal transaction and then he’s take ownership. That’s why I can’t use it from core contract.